# How to use a ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview

[image: Scroll]

This is suppose to be a scroll view with all the content added from the Java code when response is received from the API.

The problem is that I can't find a way to display the information like this in a `ScrollView`. I tried using an `ImageButton` but I couldn't get the content in it then I tried using a `Button` but still couldn't achieve the desired effect please can someone suggest a way I could do this.

```
private Button makeButton(String targetName, final String i, LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams) {
    Button in = new Button(this);
    in.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle14));
    in.setText(targetName);
    in.setWidth(360);
    in.setHeight(72);
    in.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
    in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,XSavingDetailsActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("i" ,i);
            HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    return in;
}
```

Comment: use **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)**

Comment: You should use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) .Each and every component within the RecyclerView is a [CardView](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) . Also you should learn about [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html).

Apart from the above some useful links:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview.html
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/
https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/android-cardview-101-everything-you-should-know-5bbf1c873f5a

Answer (score -1):

Just make the top-level layout a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <!-- everything else -->

</TableLayout>
```